# Form validation: "That choice is not one of the available choices."

Tags: django, post, django-forms

One of my models has a foreign key field. This field is displayed, as expected, as a drop-down (Select widget). The POSTed value for that field is a string, although the related model's ID has a default type primary key (integer):

[image]

Therefore, form validation fails while cleaning the data with:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

I have no custom form definition or validation at all. Why is the foreign key provided via select widget in form not converted to the right type?

### EDIT

The Model:

```
class Expansion(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("Created"), help_text='created on')

    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Modified"), help_text='Last modified')

    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_("Size"),
                                       help_text=_('Specify the size in GB to increase in multiple of 50'),
                                       validators=[validate_expansion_size])

    lun = models.ForeignKey(LUN, verbose_name=_('LUN'), help_text=_('Which LUN to expand'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('User'), help_text=_('Associate User'),
                             db_column='user_id')

    output = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Output"), help_text=_('The Result from the expansion'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.lun.vdisk_uuid

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        verbose_name = _('LUN Expansion')
        verbose_name_plural = _('LUN Expansions')

    # This model is backed by a REST endpoint, using django-rest-models
    class APIMeta:
        db_name = 'svc'
        resource_path = 'expansions/'
        resource_name = 'expansion'
        resource_name_plural = 'expansions'
```

The View:

```
class ExpansionCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Expansion
    template_name = 'expansion/create.html'
    form_class = ExpansionCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('expansion:index')
    success_message = _("LUN successfully expanded")

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not PSC.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
            messages.warning(self.request, _("You have not set a payment method yet. Please do this first."))
            return HttpResponseRedirect("{0:s}?next={1:s}".format(reverse('payment:create'), reverse('expansion:create')))

        if not valid_email(self.request.user.email):
            messages.warning(self.request, _("You have not set a valid email address yet. Please do this first."))
            return HttpResponseRedirect("{0:s}?next={1:s}".format(reverse('account_email'), reverse('expansion:create')))

        return super(ExpansionCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        # print(form, file=sys.stderr)
        return super(ExpansionCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The Form:

```
class ExpansionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    submit_text = _('Expand LUN')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExpansionCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

        self.helper.form_id = 'id-a2goform'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal form-label-left'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.help_text_inline = True
        self.helper.filter_by_widget(forms.Select).wrap(Field, css_class="select2_single ")
        self.helper.filter_by_widget(forms.CheckboxInput).wrap(Field, css_class="js-switch")
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', self.submit_text))

    class Meta:
        model = Expansion
        fields = ['lun', 'size']
```

The template:

```
{% extends 'content.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Expansion" %}{% endblock %}

{% block headline %}{% trans "Expand LUN" %}{% endblock %}
{% block subheadline %}{% trans "Expand" %}{% endblock %}

{% block subcontent %}
    {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}

{% block page_inline_js %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".select2_single").select2();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: POST values are _always_ strings (HTTP is text-based), and the default validator will do the necessary conversions based on your formfield's type. IOW, the problem is elsewhere - but since you didn't post a MCVE no one can tell where.

Comment: You need to at least post the view, form and template.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have been stepping through the code. It seems the `Field.to_python` method is not converting the POSTed value (string) to the field's value (primary key, I assume `int`?). No idea why is `to_python` failing to do that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, done.

Comment: Yes for a FK field it might not convert to int, but that's not necessary since the ORM accepts string values too for pk lookups (`MyClass.objects.get(pk='42')` is valid and works as expected). What I meant is that by default a ModelForm should just do the right thing here unless you messed with it.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the select2 setup in your template ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I think this has to do with the fact that my models are backed by REST via `django-rest-models`. Not sure how to solve it yet.